# How can I match an HTML group code with regex

Tags: html, regex, regex-group

I'm struggling with Regex and it's not going well.

Let's say I have this:

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="def">
        <div class="ghi">
            <div class="jkl">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to match `<div class="def">` and that `</div>` before the last one. How can I do that with regex? I use this site for help: https://regex101.com/

[image: that's what I have now]

This is my regex code: `/<div class="def">(.*)<\/div>/isU`

But it will not match the `</div>` before the last one.

Comment: You can’t do this sort of indeterminate-depth nested match with regex. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1758162#1758162. What language are you using? there are mechanisms.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thank you. I'm just trying to create a template modification with regex in XenForo software. I thought this is possible so I don't have to find/replace a bunch of code (not convenient).

Comment: I'm just adding my "don't do this". May be better off using something like BeautifulSoup from Python's bs4 package.

Comment: Just to add... I am trying to edit a simple HTML template with a regex HTML template modification. But from the comments, I can see I rather not do it or it's not even possible.

Comment: HTML is (mostly) xml. I suspect you can manipulate it like this - https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5?amp=1

Comment: If you included a programming language, it would be possible to do this with regex.